# How can I change the line spacing in a spinner?

Tags: android, xml, mobile

[[image]]
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1olP.png)Hey need just a bit help here ^^
Im trying to do a spinner in AS.
But cant change the line spacing.

```
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:padding="10dp"


    >
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `textView.setLineSpacing()` with code or `android:lineSpacingExtra`or `android:lineSpacingMultiplier` with xml as bellow:

```
<TextView
    ... 
    android:lineSpacingExtra="xxdp"
    <!-- or android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.2" if number is greater than 1 -->
    />
```